# Turn off verbose_logging for single Chef recipes or resources

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo, knife, knife-solo

I have a recipe which copies a secret_key to my node. Actually the file content is logged into my shell. I want to turn that off for this single recipe, because I don't want the file content to be saved into my shell history. I know that it's possible to completely deactivate the logging with the verbose_logging setting in client.rb.

> verbose_logging:
>   Set the log level. Options: true, nil, and false.
>   When this is set to false, notifications about individual resources
>   being processed are suppressed (and are output at the :info logging
>   level). Setting this to false can be useful when a chef-client is run
>   as a daemon. Default value: nil.

But is it possible to deactivate the logging only for a single recipe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a [common property](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html) called `sensitive`, which will

> Ensure that sensitive resource data is not logged by the chef-client. Default value: false. This property only applies to the execute, file and template resources.

```rb
template "/etc/my.secret" do
  sensitive true
end
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: As a warning, this only applies to execute resources in Chef 12. 11 and earlier will still show the command and output.

Comment: Only _execute_ or (_execute, file and template_) as mentioned in the docs? Interesting to read that this does not work in Chef 11 (the property exists but it does nothing?).